# How do I get a graphical installer for Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: boot, command-line, gnome

I'm trying to install Ubuntu GNOME over my vanilla Ubuntu installation. I've downloaded the amd64 version of Ubuntu GNOME through torrent (since I have a 64-bit processor), and the md5sum checks out. I used the Startup Disk Creator to install the ISO into my usb. Everything goes fine so far.

Now I boot from the usb, and it gives me the error:

```
Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path
gfxboot.c32:not a COM32R image
boot:
```

I searched online, and people said to type `live` to continue the boot. `live` went through, and after the GNOME icon loading screen, it boots to a full screen terminal.

What do I do from here, or did I do something wrong? How can I get a graphical installer like vanilla Ubuntu has?

Comment: did you get the torrent from here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME ? It should be a graphical installer just like vanilla Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install it "over" your existing vanilla installation, you can do that through the software center. It's called ubuntu-gnome-desktop. You can also install this by opening a terminal and typing the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```